# Hazelcast embedded distributed cache is not working on both Kubernetes & TCP discovery modes

Tags: hazelcast

We are using hazelcast version 5.3.0. We have embedded cache topology with kubernetes discovery mode and there are 3 pods in the application. The same application is hosted on Cloud VMs with TCP discovery in other region. Though the hazelcast is able to form the cluster among the pods / vm instances during the application start up, the cache data is not getting synchronized between them and they behave like standalone cache. We didn't face this issue in the earlier versions of hazelcast. Can some one help to troubleshoot the issue

We have recycled the pods from OpenShift cluster but still no luck

We have got the below warning from pod logs after passing 24 hrs from restart

[Node-A-IP]:5701 [hazelcast-reports] [5.3.0] Connection[id=3, /Node-A-IP:5701->/Node-B-IP:45422, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, remoteUuid=null, alive=false, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=3, /Node-A-IP:5701->/Node-B-IP:45422, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, remoteUuid=null, alive=true, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1], thread=hz.clever_gould.IO.thread-in-2